# Formatting a List properly with python

Tags: python-2.7, list, tuples, geocoding, kml

I'm not sure, probably the answer is somewhere here allready, but due to my "noob-status" it is very difficult for me to understand if the allready asked questions really have something to do with my problem and believe me, I've tried to find a solution since yesterday morning and I have to be done tomorrow, so here i go:

I need to write a Script with Python27 which automatically converts a given CSV-file with Coordinates into a KML-file which can be used for google earth.

This is what I got so far:

```
# imports the module urllib2 to open URLs
import urllib2
# ask for URL and load it
# Bsp.: http://koenigstuhl.geog.uni-heidelberg.de/~bhoefle/geoscripting/GPS_track_HD_Bodensee.csv
URL = raw_input("Enter the URL to your CSV-file: ")
response = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
html = response.read()
#print html

Zielverzeichnis = raw_input("Enter the path where you would like to store the file:")
Dateiname = "/" + raw_input("Name your file:") + ".kml"
#print Dateiname
#print Zielverzeichnis
#print Zielverzeichnis + Dateiname
Tabelle = Zielverzeichnis + Dateiname
fileobj = file(Tabelle, "w")
with open(Tabelle, "w") as writefile:
    writefile.write(html)


#import csv
#data = csv.reader(open(Tabelle), delimiter = ',')
f = open(Tabelle, 'w')
f.write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n")
f.write("<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>\n")
f.write("<Placemark>\n")
f.write("<name>" + Dateiname +"</name>\n")
f.write("<MultiGeometry>\n")
f.write("<LineString>\n")
f.write("<coordinates>\n")

html2 = html.split()
Koordinaten = html2[3:1003]


#Koordinaten.insert([n*30], ]])
f.writelines(Koordinaten)

f.close()
#with open(Tabelle) as rfile:
#    lines = rfile.readlines()[1:1001]
#    print lines
#    linevalues = lines.split(",")
#    firstval = float(linevalues[0])
#    secondval = float(linevalues[1])
#    print firstval, secondval
```

The Stuff at the end are/were just ideas of how to solve it. If you execute the script you will see that the fist 1000 coordinates are pasted into the file, but how do i seperate the three Values for lat/long/elevation and put them in the order neccessary for google earth (long/lat/elevation)? I would be very glad to hear from you soon!
Thanks

EDIT:
Right now it looks like that:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
<Placemark>
<name>/Testfile.xml</name>
<MultiGeometry>
<LineString>
<coordinates>
49.40336870,8.681468410,117.049.40212450,8.680264000,118.049.40083450,8.678729290,112.049.39974100,8.676724960,115.049.39909890,8.675406580,113.049.39823150,8.673896850,111.049.39741020,8.672800160,111.049.39693920,8.671590970,111.049.39594540,8.669930680,110.049.39212020,8.665451860,111.049.38969310,8.662548160,110.049.38685910,8.658890010,109.049.38423320,8.655726650,110.049.37958570,8.650085210,110.049.37725820,8.647567880,108.049.37616580,8.646088460,110.049.37584310,8.646435030,109.049.37551880,8.646217030,110.049.37448140,8.645122860,107.0
```

And i need it to look like that:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
<Placemark>
<name>/Testfile.xml</name>
<MultiGeometry>
<LineString>
<coordinates>
  49.40336870,8.681468410,117.0
  49.40212450,8.680264000,118.0
  49.40083450,8.678729290,112.0
  49.39974100,8.676724960,115.0
  49.39909890,8.675406580,113.0
  49.39823150,8.673896850,111.0
  49.39741020,8.672800160,111.0
  49.39693920,8.671590970,111.0
  49.39594540,8.669930680,110.0
  49.39212020,8.665451860,111.0
  49.38969310,8.662548160,110.0
  49.38685910,8.658890010,109.0
  49.38423320,8.655726650,110.0
  49.37958570,8.650085210,110.0
  49.37725820,8.647567880,108.0
  49.37616580,8.646088460,110.0
  49.37584310,8.646435030,109.0
  49.37551880,8.646217030,110.0
  49.37448140,8.645122860,107.0
```

With one difference: the values 49.xy (latitude) and 8.xy (longitude) should be changed as well.

Comment: Your commented out code is almost there. `lines` is a list so you won't be able to do `linevalues = lines.split(",")`. You'll need to use a `for` loop to iterate over each element in `lines` and then split by `,` and then write the output of that `split` in whichever order you need.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay, but I just dont get it right now, trying it since half an hour again now and this is what i got so far, allthough i'm pretty sure it's useless:
`for lines in Koordinaten:
    f.write("%s" % lines)
    lines.split(,)`
obviously it's wrong too.

Comment: Can you put an example of a couple of lines from `Tabelle` and your expected lines in your new file in your question.

Comment: here you go, thanks for helping btw!

Comment: Can you show the first few elements of `Koordinaten`. Also, why don't you just write everything all at once, rather than writing, closing and then trying to rewrite the coordinates again?

Comment: 'Koordinaten' is this: '['49.40336870,8.681468410,117.0', '49.40212450,8.680264000,118.0', '49.40083450,8.678729290,112.0', '49.39974100,8.676724960,115.0', '49.39909890,8.675406580,113.0', '49.39823150,8.673896850,111.0', '49.39741020,8.672800160,111.0', '49.39693920,8.671590970,111.0', '49.39594540,8.669930680,110.0', '49.39212020,8.665451860,111.0',', to your last question, I saw that too but was afraid that if i changed it i might break sth and have to start again. It should be much more simple but if i really don't know something, i tend to think too complicated than neccessary

Comment: So `Koodinaten` is a string?

Comment: yes it is a string

Comment: And it looks exactly like how you posted above? Starts with a `'['` and ends with a `','`? Or is that only the start of the string?

Comment: Actually I just read your code again. `Koodinaten` can't be a string because it's a result of `split` which means it's a list. Can you post it exactly how it looks in your question.

Comment: It goes on and on, ecery time 3 Coordinates and it ends with ]:
['49.40336870,8.681468410,117.0', '49.40212450,8.680264000,118.0', '49.40083450,8.678729290,112.0', '49.39974100,8.676724960,115.0', '49.39909890,8.675406580,113.0', '49.39823150,8.673896850,111.0', '49.39741020,8.672800160,111.0', '49.39693920,8.671590970,111.0', '49.39594540,8.669930680,110.0', '49.39212020,8.665451860,111.0',]

just that there are 1000 times three coordinates

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend opening the file only once and writing everything, rather than opening and closing multiple times.

The problem is this line:
    `f.writelines(Koordinaten)`

Instead of this, use:

```
f.write('\n'.join(Koordinaten))
```

Comment: when i use that it just says "none". My solution would be sth like
`Koordinaten.insert( 1, "\n")
Koordinaten.insert( 3, "\n")
Koordinaten.insert( 5, "\n")
Koordinaten.insert( 7, "\n")
Koordinaten.insert( 9, "\n")
Koordinaten.insert( 11, "\n")`

can i use a loop function somehow so that it just repeats itself until 999? Like that the format would allready fit and i just needed to change row one and row two of `Koordinaten` somehow

Comment: What do you mean by just says "none"? Where does it say none?